# Unable to proceed with Facebook Login with 1 denied permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-permissions

So after updating my facebook app to the latest version yesterday, i.e December 7, 2017 I noticed a strange behavior with facebook login and it happens in the case of single denied permission. In single denied permission, facebook shows a new interface - something like this[image]

So the issue is if the user logged in earlier by granting 2/3 permissions, logs out and then attempts to login with facebook, he's presented with this interface and if he chooses `not now` then the callback goes to `onCancel()` method of loginManager.
Prior to this latest update of facebook, it simply showed the interface that allows user to edit permissions asked by the app and if the user chooses to not allow, the callback still goes to `onSuccess()` which is not the case now due to this new interface. The old interface still shows if the user had multiple denied permissions, that is why I mentioned this happens only if there is single denied permission.

So how do I keep the same flow as earlier, i.e allow the user to login into the app even after denying a permission?

**NOTE:** Facebook version used is `152.0.0.42.136` (update available on Dec 4, 2017)

**EDIT** : So I wrote to *Facebook's Direct Support* about this issue giving them steps to replicate the same and they have **confirmed its a bug** and have opened a ticket for the same. I'll update everyone when that ticket is closed and the issue is resolved.

Comment: I don’t see an actual question here.

Comment: @CBroe Well, I'm sorry if I'm not clear, but the issue is that the user is unable to login back again even though he was able to do that earlier in case he denied a permission, say his email or friend list. Earlier, facebook used to return the token, but now it simply goes to onCancel method and hence the user is unable to login.

Comment: _“but the issue is [...]”_ - yeah, great, we know what the issue is by now - but this is still not a _question_. What do you expect us to do about the issue now? If Facebook broke something with an update, then file a bug report with them.

Comment: I posted the question here first hoping someone might have found a solution or work around for this issue. Anyways, wrote about the same to Facebook's Direct Support. I'll update once I hear back from them.